# iPhone - Connection String and DB File

Tags: iphone, sqlite, configuration, xamarin.ios

I am developing a iPhone app using Monotouch.  I need to access a Sqlite DB.  In my soultion, I have a contracts, data access, business access and UI project.  I have two questions:

1. Where should I keep my DB file?  Originally, I put it in the data access project.  When I compile my business access project it copies the DB file to the output, but when I compile my UI project it does not (UI has a reference to business access which has a ref to data access).  I moved it to the UI project, but it feels wrong to keep it there.
2. Where should I keep the connection string to the DB?  Is there a concept of config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we do:

We ship a copy of the DB in the application. It is included as Content, Always Copy in the project.

On the user's machine, it is stored in the special directory `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`.

When the app is started, we check to see if the database exists on the user's system and, if not, copy it there.

The connection string is just `"Data Source=" + sDatabasePath`.

Here is a sample of the code that we use for this (I hacked in the connection stuff since we use a homebuilt class for managing the DB, but you should get the idea):

```
const string DATABASE_FILE_NAME = "MyDB.db3";
bool fSuccess = false;
DbConnection conn = new DbConnection ();

string sApplicationDir = Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MyApplicationSubDir");
if (!Directory.Exists (sApplicationDir)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory (sApplicationDir);
}

// Generate the directory to the database file
string sDatabaseDir = Path.Combine (sApplicationDir, "Database");
m_sDatabaseDir = sDatabaseDir;

if (!Directory.Exists (sDatabaseDir)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory (sDatabaseDir);
}

// Generate the path to the database file
string sDatabasePath = Path.Combine (sDatabaseDir, DATABASE_FILE_NAME);
m_sDatabaseFile = sDatabasePath;

// If the file does not not exist
if (!File.Exists (sDatabasePath)) {
    // Copy the base implementation
    File.Copy (Path.Combine (Path.Combine (Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Database"), DATABASE_FILE_NAME), sDatabasePath);
}

// Initialize the DB
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + sDatabasePath;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  To answer my questions, I believe you 1) put the DB file in the UI project 2) don't have a config file

Answer (score 1):

out of interest, have you looked at sqlite-net ? http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/

Makes your DB handling a lot easier.